# not return store data in angulae when initial component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

i have a component in my project . in this project i have a list component . in this component i need when the component is Initial , load the store by this code :

```
constructor(private store: Store<any>,private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

      this.store.pipe(select('products')).subscribe(
    products => {
      if (products) {
        this.displayCode = products.showProductCode;
      }
    });
}
```

and this is the reducder:

```
    export function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'TOGGLE_PRODUCT_CODE':
      return {
        ...state,
        showProductCode: action.payload
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and this is module :

```
    StoreModule.forFeature('products', reducer)
```

**but when i initial the component it not load the store value of products and it show me `undefined` . whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???**

Comment: the data is coming from your ProductService, not from your store. The store is injected here but not used.

Comment: @GérômeGrignon sorry for this mistake. i update the question

Answer (score 1):

Assign state to the initial state in your reducer

```
//                            
export function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'TOGGLE_PRODUCT_CODE':
      return {
        ...state,
        showProductCode: action.payload
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: i want return last changed store . if i create a inital every time it return the inital value